# Why can't this public member function call decltype on a private struct member declared inside the class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, decltype, visual-studio-2013

The following code, which loosely represents some serialization stuff I'm working on, compiles with g++ (http://ideone.com/0rsGmt), but Visual Studio Express 2013 RC fails with the following errors:

```
Error 1 error C2326: 'void foo::print(void)' : function cannot access 'foo::bar::member_'
Error 2 error C2039: 'bar' : is not a member of 'foo'
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{   
    private:
        struct bar
        {
            int member_;
        };

    public:
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << sizeof(decltype(foo::bar::member_)) << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo f;
    f.print();
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong? Visual Studio inadequacy or something else? Obviously I can move the struct declaration out of the class; and Daniel Frey has offered a workaround below; but I want to know **why** the above code won't compile as-is with Visual Studio.

**Update:** The accepted answer says that it should work, but as is typical for Microsoft it doesn't. I've filled a bug report here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801829/incomplete-decltype-support-in-c-11-compiler

(If someone can suggest a better title for the question, I'd appreciate it!)

Comment: Try moving `bar` on top of `print`, i.e., change the order.

Comment: @DanielFrey, I swapped them around but still get the same error in Visual Studio Express 2013 RC.

Comment: For what its worth (and that probably isn't much), this compiles fine on clang 3.2. Likewise so does `decltype(bar::member_)` (i.e. no `foo`).

Comment: Downvoter: Please suggest how the question can be improved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code *should* work (as on GCC or Clang), according to

> #### 5 Expressions [expr]
>
> <sup>8</sup> In some contexts, *unevaluated operands* appear (5.2.8, 5.3.3, 5.3.7, 7.1.6.2). An unevaluated operand is not evaluated. An unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression. [*Note:* In an unevaluated operand, a non-static class member may be named (5.1) and naming of objects or functions does not, by itself, require that a definition be provided (3.2). — *end note* ]

It seems that VC++ does not implement what the note clarifies, so you need a (faked) instance as a work-around to make VC++ happy. This should work:

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::declval<bar>().member_) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I removed the `decltype` as `sizeof` can work on expressions directly.

Comment: Is there a runtime cost doing it this way? The 'real' code has many struct members with decltype called on them in many places. Speed isn't crucial here, but it looks a bit smelly! Especially because g++ can handle it as intended.

Comment: @DrTwox No, there is no run-time overhead. [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is only declared but not defined, so it can only be used in unevaluated contexts, meaning no code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with your code is that structs are like classes and you define the struct inside the class but the compiler does not know that this class(or struct) exists until it compiles the whole class.

Comment: I assure you the location of `struct bar` was intentional, and the fundamental root of the reason the OP is asking this question in the first place. He's not just asking how to get something that compiles. He's asking why what he has *doesn't* compile with regards to usage of `decltype()`.

Comment: I know, and I just said the probable reason.